# Reading Managed PE DLLs

Tags: .net, dll, managed, specifications, portable-executable

I want my application, written in ocaml, to read a managed DLL and retrieve the class definitions contained therein. Where can I find the public documentation / example code on how to do it?

[edit:
Since I'm writing this application in ocaml, I'm looking for actual file format definitions, since I can't use the .NET's own assembly inspection functions]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found some relevant pieces of information about reading a PE file and the CLI metadata. Specifically, this article http://wyday.com/blog/2010/how-to-detect-net-assemblies-x86-x64-anycpu/ has an example source code in C# and links to the [PE/COFF specification](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/pecoff.mspx), and to the [CLI Metadata specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20II.pdf) . It seems they will be enough to get started.

I will still leave this question open, though, if someone would like to share more specific information / example source code. Thanks again for everyone that answered!

Comment: Just stumbled on this question again. Well, I ended up implementing the OCaml code using a lot of trial-and-error. The code is at https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/ocamllibs/tree/master/ilib

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal file specification available, mostly because it is subject to change and *has* changed several times (.NET 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0).  A structural description of the metadata tables in the assembly manifest is available in [Ecma 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).  The Windows SDK's CorHdr.h file contains essential declarations, but is only directly usable from C or C++.

Nobody ever tries to read the file directly.  Instead you use the metadata api, [IMetaDataImport2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232953.aspx).  Good examples are widely available, the name googles well.  The SSCLI20 project has source code for ildasm and the C# compiler that shows this interface being used.  The [CCI Metadata project](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) could be very useful as well, designed to help you implement compilers, short from it probably not being useful directly in OCaml.

Beware that IMetaDataImport is a COM interface so the degree of pain you'll suffer trying to port this to OCaml will depend a great deal on how well your implementation supports COM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I'm a little worried, though, about not being able to do it without an external API. Not only the project I'm working on tries to be as dependency-less as possible, it must also support Mac and Linux, at least!

Comment: IMetaDataImport is very much an "external API".  It is a COM api, like many of the more advanced Windows apis, the kind where not having something a resembling an object model is too painful.

Answer (score 1):

This Code should help you to start

```
 Assembly dLL = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
 foreach (Type type in dLL.GetTypes())
 {
  //...play with type here
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I haven't made it totally clear that I'm writing the application in ocaml, so I can't use the Assembly inspection methods from .NET.

Comment: @Waneck oups, you told about managed DLL, which means dll contains managed code, which means it will be exectued in CLR, which means you should be able to load and inspect it's properties in . NET :)

Comment: I only need to read the definitions to use inside my own compiler, not to actually execute any code :)